# Collision between Sprite and Tile map

Tags: c++, dictionary, sprite, collision, sfml

How to create/define a collision between Sprite of character and Tile of map in SFML libriary? I want my player to be able to recognise when he hits the wall.

Answer (score 0):

In SFML you have no Tile class. But probably you are able to create sf::FloatRect which describe your Tile rect.

Sprite class have method

```
FloatRect   getGlobalBounds () const
```

which also give you sf::FloatRect and when you will have both rects you will be able to use this method from sf::FloatRect:

```
bool    intersects (const Rect< T > &rectangle) const
```

To see if they colide. Now you need to check this collision to elements of map which are close to your player.

Comment: Yes i understand that but how can i make bounding box to exactly one tile from the whole map?

Comment: If you have tilemap, then you probably know start position of tile sprite and size of tile. If your starting pos isn't sf::Vector, then it is probably a index in array? So if you know size and index you can calculate position of tile. If you have position and size you can create sf::FloatRect.

If yours map is one big image divided into tiles only from graphic view you need to create something like logic tile map, which will remember position and size of blocking tiles.